# Client side ESP32 WROOM not receiving the correct data

Tags: microcontroller, esp32

I am establishing a wireless communication between two ESP32 WROOMs and then send data from one ESP to another. One ESP is in AP mode (acting as server) while the other is in ST Mode (acting as client). To test the connection, I generated random values from the server ESP and tried to receive them in the client ESP. Communication has been established between both the server and the client, but when random numbers are sent from the server to the client, the output doesn't match with the random numbers being sent.

Why is this happening ?

[image]

Server side code:

```
#include <WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "access_point_SSID";
const char* password = "access_point_PASSWORD";


IPAddress local_ip(192, 168, 4, 1);
IPAddress gateway(192, 168, 4, 1);
IPAddress subnet(255, 255, 255, 0);
int port = 80;


WiFiServer server(port);

void setup() {
  // Start the serial communication
  Serial.begin(115200);
  

  // Connect to WiFi network
  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
  delay(100);

  // Configure the access point
  WiFi.softAPConfig(local_ip, gateway, subnet);

  // Start the server
  server.begin();
  Serial.println("Server started");
}

void loop() {
  // Wait for a client to connect
  WiFiClient client = server.available();
  if (client) 
  {
    Serial.println("New client connected");
    // Wait for data from the client

    while (client.connected()) 
    {
        int random = esp_random();
        Serial.println(random);
        client.println(random);                   
      }
    }
  }
```

Client Side Code:

```
#include <WiFi.h>

const char* ssid = "access_point_SSID";
const char* password = "access_point_PASSWORD";


IPAddress server_ip(192, 168, 4, 1);
int port = 80;

// Create a WiFiClient object
WiFiClient client;

void setup() {
  // Start the serial communication
  Serial.begin(115200);

  // Connect to WiFi network
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to WiFi...");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to WiFi");

  // Connect to the server
  while (!client.connect(server_ip, port)) {
    delay(1000);
    Serial.println("Connecting to server...");
  }
  Serial.println("Connected to server");
}

void loop() {
  // Check for incoming data from the server
  while (client.available()) {
    // Read the incoming data from the server
    int data = client.read();

    // Print the incoming data to the serial monitor
    Serial.println(data);
  }


  
}
```

Comment: With `client.println()` You're sending 32-bit integers in ASCII (including newline characters), but the `client.read()` function only returns single 8-bit bytes.

Comment: so what should i do?

Comment: please do not post a picture of text ... add all info as text, including the content of serial monitor

Comment: keep reading characters, storing them in a String, until you hit a newline character.